# How can i take time difference from minutes and hour?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I need to take hour and minutes diff but also to convert it as this type hh:mm

Example if i will have a time 12:41 and 11:31 i need to take in output 01:10

Here is what i'm trying to do

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(MINUTE,datetime,getdate()) from Table_1
```

But i'm getting only minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
Select convert(varchar(5),DateAdd(MINUTE,DateDiff(MINUTE,'2018-06-28 11:31','2018-06-28 12:41'),0),108)
```

**Returns**

01:10

**For your live test**

```
Select convert(varchar(5),DateAdd(MINUTE,DateDiff(MINUTE,datetime,GetDate()),0),108)
```

Comment: Thank you it works like a charm!But i notice that it doesnt work if the hours are bigger than 23:59.

Comment: @daadaa Happy to help

Comment: If you allow using times in different dates, then how can you know if the difference between 11:31 to 12:41 is 01:10 or maybe 25:10 and so on? You must have some limitation like "the two times are in the same date" or "the two times are in the same 24 hours". With adding this limitation of 24 hours you can simply use CASE statement and when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @T2, @T1) is less then 0 then you add the time 24 hours

Comment: @RonenAriely You are correct.  I did make the assumption OP was working in the same day.

Comment: I actually wrote a full explanation including the issue of missing information regarding Dates. I also explain why this action make no sense (like asking what is DOG MINUS DOG there is no math operation between times and any solutions based on Time and Date)... but since the OP already marked your answer I simply moved t the next question. By the way, in my solution I am not using any explicit CONVERT but fast simple functions like DATEDIFF and TIMEFROMPARTS (convert between types si something that in some cases can be performance issue but in this case I did not tested the performance).

Comment: @RonenAriely Please, post your solution,  I'd be happy to UpVote and suggest OP Accepts your answer.  Just an observation, OP is on 2008 so timefromparts is not available.  And just a side note.  This would have been my initial suggestion had I known OP spans days.

Comment: @RonenAriely Sorry forgot link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126223/t-sql-calculate-age-then-add-character-to-result/43126716#43126716

Comment: Please check my last response on this thread and understand why I choose not to use stackoverflow in general and posting second answer if I do come to help here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e593f2fd-d77b-4ba3-a4fc-411da33f3096/warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation?forum=transactsql

Comment: by the way, I did not noticed the tag `sql-server-2008` ;-) . I do not come here a lot, and I am not familiar with the system interface fully. I basically came back here for specific reason after a long time (if you are Microsoft MVP I can give more information in private, but it is not really important). Anyhow, since the OP used the tag `sql-server-2008` hen as you said TIMEFROMPARTS is not relevant and in this case it was good that I did not publish the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the datediff in mins and add it to an arbitrary date and cast it to TIME.

```
DECLARE @test1 TIME = '12:41'
DECLARE @test2 TIME = '11:31'

DECLARE @diff INT
SELECT @DIFF = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @test2, @test1)
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, @diff, '1900-01-01') AS TIME)
```