# Difference in Days Between Two Dates with Years, Months, and Days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not a SQL expert, would you know if it's possible to have a query provide Days Between Two    Dates to count days outstanding with today's date and output: Years, Months, Days and outstanding days providing 30 Days, 60 Days, 90 Days?

If I Declare "Years, Months, Days" from "Check_Date" and "Created_Date".
SQL provides a separate window, and, I only see Declared "FromDate" time
with "ToDate" displaying total Years, Months, Days. I am looking for a way
to have results provide a roll BY "Created_Date" records and include:
Years, Months, Days and outstanding days providing 30 Days, 60 Days, 90 Days? Can you suggest something with a similar result?

Scrip Code:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 
        @ToDate   DATETIME = '2019-09-18 00:00:00',
        @Years INT, @Months INT, @Days INT, @tmpFromDate DATETIME
SET @Years = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate)
 - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate),
          @FromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
 
    
SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(YEAR, @Years , @FromDate)
SET @Months =  DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate)
 - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate),
          @tmpFromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    
SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(MONTH, @Months , @tmpFromDate)
SET @Days =  DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate)
 - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate),
          @tmpFromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    
SELECT @FromDate FromDate, @ToDate ToDate, 
       @Years Years,  @Months Months, @Days Days
 


SELECT DISTINCT  
ge.Name, --table columns
ge.Entity_Type, 
ge.Entity_Number, 
bc.Super_Entity_ID, 
ch.Check_Date, --check created
ch.Created_Date, --if payment was received
ch.Check_Number, 
ch.Amount,
vn.Vendor_Name



Check_Date,Created_Date,DATEDIFF("DAY",Check_Date,Created_Date) AS DAY


FROM dbo.gl_entities AS ge
INNER JOIN
dbo.super_entity AS se
ON ge.Super_Entity_ID = se.Super_Entity_ID 
INNER JOIN
dbo.bank_codes AS bc
ON se.Super_Entity_ID = bc.Super_Entity_ID 
INNER JOIN
dbo.checks AS ch
ON bc.Bank_Code_ID = ch.Bank_Code_ID 
INNER JOIN
dbo.vendors AS vn
ON ch.Vendor_ID = vn.Vendor_ID


WHERE 
ge.Active = 1 and vn.active = 1 and (ge.IS_Shadow = 1 OR se.IS_Tiered = 0)

AND CHECK_DATE > '20150101 00:00:00'
AND CHECK_DATE< '20190918 00:00:00'

ORDER BY ch.Check_Date, ch.Created_Date
```

Comment: Transforming to years/months/days is much more complicated than you imagine.  What is the difference between 2019-02-28 and 2019-03-01?  2019-03-27?  2019-03-28?  Or 2019-01-31 and 2019-01-28?  Or 2016-02-29 and 2017-02-28?  Or 2017-03-01?

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126223/t-sql-calculate-age-then-add-character-to-result/43126716#43126716   Specifically the "Just to Illustrate" portion

Comment: I am thinking that if my check date 2015-01-01 / 2015-08-01 was the created Date for the payment in full amount check then I should have 8 Days, however, I need to know the total amount from these old dates with Today's current date, 2019-23-09.

Comment: It looks like you already have the code for years, months, days.  I'm not sure I understand what isn't working correctly.  Are you trying to combine the first select results with the 2nd select results?  Clarify what you mean by "separate window" and "roll by".

Comment: @avery_larry, when I run my code I get years/Months/Days for only 1 result based on DECLARE From Date - ToDate. I would like to see next to ch.Created_Date all Years/Months/Days going down on column rows.

Comment: Just add them to the select?

Answer (score 0):

To simply repeat them in their own columns in the query:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 
        @ToDate   DATETIME = '2019-09-18 00:00:00',
        @Years INT, @Months INT, @Days INT, @tmpFromDate DATETIME
SET @Years = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate)
 - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate),
          @FromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 


SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(YEAR, @Years , @FromDate)
SET @Months =  DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate)
 - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate),
          @tmpFromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(MONTH, @Months , @tmpFromDate)
SET @Days =  DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate)
 - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate),
          @tmpFromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 


SELECT DISTINCT  
ge.Name, --table columns
ge.Entity_Type, 
ge.Entity_Number, 
bc.Super_Entity_ID, 
ch.Check_Date, --check created
ch.Created_Date, --if payment was received
ch.Check_Number, 
ch.Amount,
vn.Vendor_Name,
Check_Date,Created_Date,DATEDIFF("DAY",Check_Date,Created_Date) AS DAY,
@FromDate FromDate, @ToDate ToDate, @Years Years,  @Months Months, @Days Days

FROM
. . .
```

If you run into problems with the DISTINCT clause, you can always use a subquery.  If you want Years, Months, Days to be different based on one of the columns, you'll have to elaborate and then we can move everything you did in the SET statements into the SELECT statement.

Without your tables and data I cannot test very well.

Comment: I added updated code with SELECT, and FromDate with ToDate listed, DATETIME = '2015-01-01 00:00:00',  with, DATETIME = '2019-09-18 00:00:00'. Is there a way to have the script calculate the Years, Months, Days from SELECT DISTINCT - Check_Date and Created_Date?

Comment: SET Statements do provide the Year, Months, Days. Is it possible to move all into SELECT statements, where, it will provide Year, Month, Days per row only from ch.Check_Date with ch.Created_Date? Perhaps we can optimize script with GETDATE, utilizing DATEDIFF?

Comment: Check_Date,Created_Date,DATEDIFF("DAY",Check_Date,Created_Date) AS DAYS

  ,datediff(YEAR,Created_Date,GETDATE()) as Years
     ,datediff(MONTH,Created_Date,GETDATE()) %12 as Months
  ,datediff(DAYOFYEAR,Created_Date,GETDATE()) %31 as DAY

Comment: It gets messy.  But really you replace all the variables in the select statement with their corresponding set statement.  In the case where you need an intermediate answer you'll have to use subqueries to generate the intermediate values.

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode to try and demonstrate moving set statements to select statements

```
declare @begin date = '2018-01-01'
declare @end date = '2019-01-01'

declare @middletest int = datediff("dd", @begin, @end)/2
declare @middledate date = dateadd("dd", @middletest, @begin)
declare @middlemonth int = month(@middledate)

select @middlemonth half_month, @middledate middle_date
   -- ,other_columns here
from table
where something
```

Start replacing.
@middlemonth is in the select statement so replace it with month(@middledate).

```
declare @begin date = '2018-01-01'
declare @end date = '2019-01-01'

declare @middletest int = datediff("dd", @begin, @end)/2
declare @middledate date = dateadd("dd", @middletest, @begin)

select month(@middledate) half_month, @middledate middle_date
   -- ,other_columns here
from table
where something
```

@middledate is now in the select statement in 2 places so replace it with dateadd("dd", @middletest, @begin) each time.

```
declare @begin date = '2018-01-01'
declare @end date = '2019-01-01'

declare @middletest int = datediff("dd", @begin, @end)/2

select month(dateadd("dd", @middletest, @begin)) half_month,
    dateadd("dd", @middletest, @begin) middle_date
    -- ,other_columns here
from table
where something
```

Continue along.

```
declare @begin date = '2018-01-01'
declare @end date = '2019-01-01'

select month(dateadd("dd", datediff("dd", @begin, @end)/2, @begin)) half_month,
    dateadd("dd", datediff("dd", @begin, @end)/2, @begin) middle_date
    -- ,other_columns here
from table
where something
```

And you can, as desired, replace things with values from the table.  If the table has a column start_date and you want that to be the begin and then use the current date as the end:

```
select month(dateadd("dd", datediff("dd", start_date, getdate())/2, start_date)) half_month,
    dateadd("dd", datediff("dd", start_date, getdate())/2, start_date) middle_date
    -- ,other_columns here
from table
where something
```