# How to get the datediff in minutes and seconds between two dates ignoring the date being greater or lesser

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to get the date diff in HH:MM:SS between two datetime when either of the date can be leading or lagging even by few seconds. But in below example, if @date2 is leading by a sec , then the result shows  23:59:59 but it should be  00:00:01.

```
DECLARE @Date1 datetime
DECLARe @Date2 datetime
set @Date1='6/30/2023 11:06:39 AM'
set @Date2='6/30/2023 11:06:40 AM'

select left(CONVERT(varchar(12),DATEADD(s,DATEDIFF(s, @Date2, @Date1), 0), 114),8)
```

I would like to ignore the negative datetime and get the difference between the dates.

How do I add ABS and get the time format?

Comment: Can `@Date1` and `@Date2` be 24hours or more apart?

Comment: Side note, there aren't 30 months in a year; use unambiguous date formats.

Comment: Perhaps more than what you are looking for, but take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126223/t-sql-calculate-age-then-add-character-to-result/43126716#43126716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the difference can't be 24 hours or more, then why not add the difference in seconds to the `time` `00:00:00`?

```sql
DECLARE @Date1 datetime;
DECLARe @Date2 datetime;
SET @Date1 = TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),'6/30/2023 11:06:39 AM',101); --Use an unambiguous date format, at least as there aren't 30 months in a year, we can tell what value this is meant to be.
SET @Date2 = TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),'6/30/2023 11:06:40 AM',101); --Use an unambiguous date format, at least as there aren't 30 months in a year, we can tell what value this is meant to be.

SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@Date1,@Date2)),CONVERT(time(0),'00:00:00'));
```

Comment: this gives the result as  12:00:01 AM not 00:00:01 AM

Comment: That's a display issue, not a data issue, @unicorn . Your application is displaying `time`s in the format `hh:mm:ss am/pm` rather than `HH:mm:ss`. Though `00:00:01 AM` makes no sense, as there's no `00:00:01 PM`. The above returns the *`time`* `00:00:01`, how you chose to display that is up to you.

Comment: yeah sorry not 00:00:01 AM. i meant just 00:00:01. let me try if i can format it..

Comment: CONVERT(time(0),'00:00:00') gives theformat in AM/PM.. 
  i changed it to left(convert(varchar(12),DATEADD(SECOND,ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@Date1 ,@Date2)),0),114),8). this works..

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of returning a `varchar` for a `time`.

Comment: *"CONVERT(time(0),'00:00:00') gives theformat in AM/PM..'* it doesn't, it has no format, it's a binary value; what your presentation layer formats that as is up to your presentation layer (and you).[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jmY4xOro)